# UDF for index match combo using instr vba excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I wrote this code for a UDF but it taker a lot of time to calculate when i use it in many cells. Is there a more efficient way?

```
Public Function AGSIndexMatch(result_column As Range, lookup As Range, _
                                           lookup_column As Range) As Variant
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim b As String
    Dim i As Variant
    i = 1
    For Each cel In lookup_column
        On Error GoTo error_handler:
        If Not IsEmpty(cel) Then
            If InStr(1, cel.Value, lookup) <> 0 Then
                AGSIndexMatch = AGSIndexMatch & Application _
                  .WorksheetFunction.Index(result_column, i, 1) & Chr(10)
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next cel
    If Len(AGSIndexMatch) <> 0 Then
        AGSIndexMatch = Left(AGSIndexMatch, Len(AGSIndexMatch) - 1)
    End If
    Exit Function
error_handler:
    AGSIndexMatch = Err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: Are you saying this works fine as-is (with no specific problems) and you'd like advice on how to make it more efficient?  If so, this may not be the correct place for your post. **See the [help/on-topic]** for more information about what's on topic on this site, as well as "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Questions asking to make working code more efficient are possibly better suited to [Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), a question and answer site for seeking peer review of your code.

Comment: @ashleedawg [please read this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) before recommending moving to CR

Answer (score 0):

Moving the data into a Variant Array before doing the loop will improve time a lot - how much depends on the size of the ranges.

```
Public Function AGSIndexMatch( _
  result_column As Range, _
  lookup As Range, _
  lookup_column As Range) As Variant

    Dim rsc As Variant, src As Variant, lup As Variant
    rsc = result_column.Value2
    src = lookup_column.Value2
    lup = lookup.Value2
    Dim i As Long
    Dim res As String

    On Error GoTo error_handler:
    For i = 1 To UBound(src, 1)
        If src(i, 1) = lup Then
            res = res & Chr(10) & rsc(i, 1)
        End If
    Next
    AGSIndexMatch = Mid$(res, 2)

Exit Function
error_handler:
    AGSIndexMatch = Err.Description
End Function
```

There might be other ways that perform better, depending of the nature of your data

Comment: Thank you very much! that improved time a lot. i changed the if statement to better suit my needs.  ->  If InStr(1, src(i, 1), lup) <> 0 Then

Comment: also, I had to add If Not IsEmpty(lup) Then before the For so it does not make any computation if lup is empty.